# Sumo Logic: Count every matching string within a field

Tags: sumo, sumologic

I have a parsed field and I need to count the number of times a given string appears within it. It seems relatively simple, but I've been searching through Sumo documentation and now I'm not sure this is even possible. Please help!

Comment: You might need to use some regex to parse out the string: https://help.sumologic.com/05Search/Search-Query-Language/01-Parse-Operators/02-Parse-Variable-Patterns-Using-Regex. If you're willing to post a sample message I'd be happy to help with that.

Answer (score 3):

I have an idea for a hacky solution using `replace()` regex variant.

If `inputField` is your input field and you want to count the number of times `is` happens in the `inputField`, then

```
| "This is a very hacky solution which might get you in trouble" as inputField
| replace(inputField, /is/, "@") as matched
| replace(matched, /[^@]/, "") as skipTheRest
| length(skipTheRest) as finalCount
```

The solution assumes `@` is not present in the input field.

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic.

Comment: This is so good and so bad, but it gets the job done. Thank you! 

BTW - You can pre-cleanse the data by first replacing any existing @ symbols with empty strings, as an initial step.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly, we have a field A which we have parsed and now we want to match if it contains some string s.
In that case, below can be appended to your query.

```
| if(A matches "*s*", 1, 0) as ct 
| sum(ct)
```